# How Docker for Mac running Linux is different from regular virtualization?

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine, docker, container

I always thought that Docker is basically *chroot on steroids*. However I recently found one project using Docker images with Debian and tutorials were even hosted on OS X so I started digging how it's possible. It led me to information and articles describing how it uses OS X virtualization framework. But keyword here is *virtualization* so...

Is Docker with Linux images on OS X just *virtualization on steroids*? By that I mean just conventional virtualization, maybe with some better paravirtualization support but still just conventional virtualization with some easier, specialized configuration options? All in all how does it compare to running plain virtual machine?

Comment: On Linux, Docker is much lighter than a VM, because it uses the very same kernel  as its host. You can have hundreds of containers on a single machine. Try to do that with true VMs. However this requires kernel support, and AFAIK this support is absent in OSX and Windows, so on these there is specialized VM (aka "DockerMachine") that runs all the containers.

Comment: So it's 1 VM running all containers?

Comment: Yes, as I understand it (only used Docker on Linux).